# How can I run a regression that's too big for memory in R?

Tags: r, regression, large-data

I'm running a regression with ~ 87 million observations and consistently running out of memory. After searching around I tried implementing the model using `biglm` to no avail. The model has some 200 covariates (most of which are county-level fixed effects) and I have 200 GBs of RAM. The .rds itself is only about 1.3 GB.

Are there packages that allow R to run a regression not using RAM / out of memory? Or another package I'm unfamiliar with that could deal with a dataset of this size?

Comment: It depends on what kind of regression you are doing.  Ordinary Least Squares, for instance, works with the $200\times 200$ matrix (of sums of squares and products), which `R` will handle just fine and can be created in one pass through the data.  For other regressions you might have to make multiple (long, painful) passes through them.  For problems with `biglm` consider posting the code and error messages on [SO].

Comment: I think this might be the perfect kind of question for the Data Science Stack. The regression is the same with 87 observations as with 87 million, but the practical (computer) considerations for the statistician fitting the regression are different.

Comment: Investigate matrix algebra, like the inverse of a large matrix using a partitioned matrix approach, see http://www.math.chalmers.se/~rootzen/highdimensional/blockmatrixinverse.pdf . More complex, but a smaller matrix in memory.

Comment: Continuing with the inverse of a matrix, partitioned as A11, A12, A21, A22. The answer, for example, involves the inverse of A11, but one can also view this as a further application of a partitioned matrix approach, now reduced  1/4 in size,...., etc until your application can handle the RAM requirement.

Comment: @AJKOER What "large matrix" do you have in mind that is invertible?  The only apparent candidate has dimensions $200\times 200$ which is scarcely large.

Comment: Perhaps you colud look at the DBI package: https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/RProgDA/working-with-large-datasets.html

Answer (score 1):

So I have this same question coming up for myself.  I don't have a good answer, but I'd like to throw up a couple possibilities to see how people shoot them down.

1.) Process in blocks.  Take the regression for each block, doing some kind of weighted average at the end.

2.) Take advantage of svd of the covariance matrix of A having some relationship to the svd of A

[U,S,V] = svd(A)

[Uc,Sc,V] = svd(cov(A))

In both cases the matrix V is the same.

If regression is Ax = y, and A is millions x hundreds array, performing the covariance of A first may be less efficient, but more memory manageable.  I haven't figured out what to do after this step.